# Preventing CKEditor from adding 'data-cke-saved' and converting &lt

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor

I have a jQuery implementation of CKEditor. We frequently add HTML markup to the 'title' attribute of an A tag using the dialog. However when we do this, it converts the HTML code so that it is parsed as text. We need the code to stay in the exact form that it was entered in, instead of it placing 'data-cke-saved' everywhere, and converting the <> to &lt and &gt.

I have tried turning entities off in the config, but it doesn't seem to work.

Can anyone help?

Thanks.

Comment: It is not a good idea to place mark-up in your title attributes. Not all browsers will render the title tooltips as you perhaps expect. As far as I am aware it is not a valid use of the attribute in the first place.

Comment: Yes I am aware of this, and it's only temporary. The reason is for the text underneath a lightbox/colorbox window. However I still need an answer to my question.

Answer (score 0):

SRC: http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.config.html#.protectedSource

List of regular expressions to be executed on input HTML, indicating HTML source code that when matched, must not be available in the WYSIWYG mode for editing.

```
 
config.protectedSource.push( /<\?[\s\S]*?\?>/g );   // PHP code
```

config.protectedSource.push( /<%[\s\S]*?%>/g );   // ASP code

config.protectedSource.push( /(]+>[\s|\S]*?</asp:[^>]+>)|(]+/>)/gi );   // ASP.Net code
 
Default Value:
    [] (empty array)