# ckeditor generated code W3C validation : there is no attribute "data-cke-saved-src"

Tags: ckeditor, w3c-validation

I am working with [CKEditor 4.0.1.1](http://ckeditor.com/blog/CKEditor-4.0.1.1-Released) in an intranet and try to validate my code with W3C markup validation service.

The validation markup service find this error :

> Error Line 547, Column 2455: **there is no attribute "data-cke-saved-src"**

```
<img alt="" data-cke-saved-src="http://portail-rep/Contents/images/Java…
```

How can i disable this functionnality of ckeditor protecting code to make my code ok for W3C validation ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Preventing CKEditor from adding 'data-cke-saved' and converting &lt](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6177667/preventing-ckeditor-from-adding-data-cke-saved-and-converting-lt)

Comment: Notice that you can reproduce this in the ckeditor demo full in adding a picture : go to source then return to editor, the code generated is : <img style="width: 440px; height: 344px;" src="/userfiles/images/Mouse.jpg" data-cke-saved-src="/userfiles/images/Mouse.jpg" alt="">

Answer (score 2):

CKEditor uses many special attributes and elements to implement some of its features. However, they are used only internally and should be stripped out when getting data by `editor.getData()`. Therefore editor produces valid markup.

E.g. open http://ckeditor.com/demo, switch to source mode and you'll see that the image doesn't have the `data-cke-saved-src` attribute. However, if you'll use Firebug or Webkit's dev tools you'll find that the image has this attribute.

PS. In fact, `data-cke-saved-src` is a [valid attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes) in HTML5.

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem now. This problem has been solved by using CKEDITOR config `on blur event`.

I'am using inline editing on element.
My ck config contain on blur event which have destroy method.

```
CKEDITOR.config.on = {
  blur: function() {
    this.destroy();
  }
}
```

**Using is simply:**
On element click will create instance of new editor and it enable inline editing.
Now if user click outside of editor and on blur event invoked, editor destroy it self and if no editor instance exist, the content of the data is cleaned from data-cke attributes.